# (Docker) Django model “doesn't declare an explicit app_label” and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, docker, django-models, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a django server, but I'm facing issues that are poorly documented.

I have a very simple Specs model defined in my models.py file, and when I try to run docker-compose I am receiving the following error message:

> RuntimeError: Model class api.models.Specs doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

I then realised that, upon following the tutorial I was using, I did not add my AppConfig name into INSTALLED_APPS, but just that was not enough to resolve the issue. I'm using a different project structure to run this docker container, and I suspect the problem might be related to the path to my apps.py file.

Here's a summarized version of the current project file structure:

> project/
>
> -app/
>
> --app/api/
>
> **---app/api/apps.py**
>
> ---app/api/controllers.py
>
> ---app/api/models.py
>
> ---app/api/views.py
>
> ---app/api/wsgi.py
>
> --app/config/
>
> ---app/config/celeryconfig.py
>
> **---app/config/settings.py**
>
> --app/someUtils/
>
> --app/manage.py
>
> -docker-compose.yml
>
> -Dockerfile
>
> -requirements.txt

I have tried using several different values for INSTALLED_APPS, like "apps.MyAppConfig", "api.apps.MyAppConfig" and "app.api.apps.MyAppConfig", but all I get are different error messages, such as "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <>".

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this? What path should I use for this appConfig in the settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS? Should I change my dockerization approach to something different (free of standard Django models)? Can anyone point me to some reliable documentation/tutorial/examples of containerisation of Django projects?

PS: Maybe I have added apps.py in the wrong folder? Again, this is not the file structure I'm used to.

Comment: Try project.app.api.

Comment: @Whodini still getting the same messages about "ModuleNotFoundError"

Comment: How about app.api?

Comment: @Whodini instead of "ModuleNotFoundError", this is accepted but I'm still getting the original RuntimeError (Model isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS)

Comment: Please post your INSTALLED_APPS.